# В maven как добавить driver jdbc postgres

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, vaadin

Я пытаюсь использовать jdbc Postgres для подключения к базе данных на Java (IDE Eclipse framework Vaadin сборка проекта maven). В pom.xml в ручную вставляю тег упаковки в банку groupId, artifactId и Version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted</version>
    </dependency>`
```

и получаю ошибки:

`Failed to execute goal on project OR: Could not resolve dependencies for project rts.appUI:OR:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted in`

Подскажите как правильно добавить driver ?

Ранее писал одну статью об ошибке java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
[вот собственно ссылка для статьи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714443/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-postgresql-driver)
Там была у меня проблема с драйвером, в данный момент при добавлении `driver org.postgresql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то у вас с версией неладное.
Может имеется ввиду эта?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.1208-atlassian-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Посмотрите в самом [репозитории](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql) какая версия вам нужна.

Comment: Благодарю! Мне ваш ответ помогла, собственно говоря не добавил тег:
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->